# Correct implementation of opening storyboard view controller from UIApplicationShortcutItem in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 3dtouch

This is the code I have got for trying to open a view controller from a storyboard. I am getting error "expected identifier" on

UINavigationController *controller = [(UINavigationController*)[[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ARViewController"];

Can someone please help.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {

NSLog(@"%@", shortcutItem.type);
if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"ADD OWN STRING HERE"]) {

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *controller = [(UINavigationController*)[[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ARViewController"]];
    [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount and locations of your `[` and `]` didn't match (two `[` too many, one `]` too many). It should be:

```
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ARViewController"];
```